# The wedge product of covectors

Tags: exterior-algebra

On a textbook, the wedge product of the covectors $\Omega$ is spanned on basis vectors $dx$ using this notation. $$\Omega^i=\Omega^i_\mu dx^{\mu}$$ 
$i$ is the name of the covector, not an index.

$$\Omega^1\wedge\Omega^2\cdots\wedge\Omega^p=\Omega^1_{i_1}dx^{i_1}\wedge\Omega^2_{i_2}dx^{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge\Omega^p_{i_p}dx^{i_p}=$$

$$=\omega^1_{i_1}\omega^2_{i_2}\omega^p_{i_p}dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_p}=$$
$$=\underset{i_1<i_2\cdots<i_p}{\sum}\underset{\sigma} {\sum}\Omega^1_{\sigma(i_1)}\Omega^2_{\sigma(i_2)}\cdots \Omega^p_{\sigma(i_p)}dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_p}$$

I don't understand why is the summation taken over the ascending sequence of $i$.

Comment: Under a rearrangement of (basis) vectors, the wedge product changes by a sign, e.g., $dx^1 \wedge dx^2 = -dx^2 \wedge dx^1$, so if you are looking for a *basis* of the wedge product space you don't need to repeat a wedge product in a different order.  A standard way to list all $p$-tuples from a set where no list appears in a rearranged form is to use lists with increasing indices. You can ignore duplicate indices in a wedge product since $dx^i \wedge dx^i = 0$.

Comment: Is the summation taken over all possible tuples?

Comment: The summation is taken over all possible *increasing* tuples.  Did you interpret that outer sum in another way?

Comment: In the first summations, $\Omega^1_{i_1}dx^{i_1}\wedge\Omega^2_{i_2}dx^{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge\Omega^p_{i_p}dx^{i_p}=\omega^1_{i_1}\omega^2_{i_2}\omega^p_{i_p}dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_p},$ every index runs over all dimensions $i_k = 1, \ldots, n$, but in the last sum, the one with explicit summations signs, only increasing tuples $(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_p)$ are used.

Comment: The summation is simplified by properties of the wedge product and taking into account $p$<dim$(\Omega)$.